# Xero API Error 500 thrown with login / signup

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xero-api

So I've been trying to learn to connect my asp.net application with the Xero API and then downloaded their XeroOAuth2Sample:
https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-netstandard-oauth2-samples/tree/master/XeroOAuth2Sample/XeroOAuth2Sample

After inserting my unique client ID and Secret key, the project successfully loads up and I am displayed with the following screen:
[image]

Once I click on the Sign in / sign up button(s), I am greeted with this Error 500:
[image]

I can not seem to understand why or how this error is being triggered. I have tried to clear my caches and cookies as recommended and ensured that the URL linked to my Xero account is valid.

Can anyone think of why this error is happening? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Hey Zadders, I built this sample app. What's your clientId, I'll look for errors on our side to see if I can see why this is failing for you.

Comment: @MJMortimer Hi, thank you for getting back to me so quickly, my clientId is as follows: B0CD448E070442A788E6CEC2DBC598C3

Comment: @MJMortimer Also, as it was you that created this sample, I was wondering if you would be able to tell me at what point the "XeroClient" is being ran during the proccess which is connecting the app? Because I am also trying to re-create this as a VB.net project and need more information regarding the httpClientFactory

Comment: The XeroClient class is dependency injected into the MemoryTokenStore and HomeController. It's used by the MemoryTokenStore each time a user is signed in/up to store the access token for the user, as well as in the HomeController to retrieve all the connected tenants for the API that the user has.

Comment: @MJMortimer Ahh I see, are these the only uses for the XeroClient ? Also is there any update(s) regarding the errors from your side?

Comment: It's also used in the MemoryTokenStore to refresh the token if needed I'm pretty sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at logs on our side shows that your redirect uris don't match up. Your app only has one redirect uri setup for http://localhost:5000/, but the sample app needs to have two redirect uris set up to work in its entirety; one for http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc and one for http://localhost:5000/signup-oidc

Comment: Ahh thank you very much! I had over-looked the github readme documentation and literally realized this error the moment you replied with this answer. I'm glad to know that it's due to the same reason

Comment: No problem at all!